# babel-register doesn't work for subsequent require statements

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router, babeljs

I'm building an isomorphic (universal) React.js app with Express.js. My server and client code share a `Routes.jsx` file employing ES2017 syntax and, well, JSX.

I understand `babel-register` should transpile this ; however, the following code generates an error when executed:

```
require('babel-register')({
  presets: [
    'es2017',
    'react',
  ]
})
const routes = require('./Routes.jsx')
```

The first line of `Routes.jsx` is:

```
import React from 'react'
```

The error is:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import React from 'react';
                                                              ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

I am absolutely baffled at why this isn’t working. The correct babel modules are installed. Thanks for pointers!

Comment: try install `npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-stage-0` and `require('babel-register')({
  presets: [
    'es2015',
    'react',
    'stage-0'
  ]
})`

Answer (score 1):

The `es2017` preset only includes newly added features for ES2017, so it will not include converting module syntax.

Using [`babel-preset-env`](https://github.com/babel/babel-preset-env) is likely your easiest option.

Comment: Thanks! It turns out I needed several other plugins and a the `babel-polyfill` too, for all the language features I'm using.